# How to define controller in angularjs with IIFE

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following code in my app.js in root directory `/app.js`

```
angular.module("ngClassifieds",[])
 .controller("classifiedsCtrl", function($scope) {
   $scope.name = "shekhar";
 });
```

Currently this is working fine, then i shift my controller inside new directory `components/classifiedCtrl.js` like this

below is my `app.js` file

```
angular.module("ngClassifieds",[]);
```

below is my controller inside components/classifiedCtrl.js

```
(function () {

  "use strict";

   angular.module("ngClassifieds")
     .controller("classifiedsCtrl", function($scope) {
     $scope.name = "shekhar";
   });

}) ();
```

Now it is gives me the error   `Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'classifiedsCtrl' is not a function, got undefined`

I am using angular version `1.5.7`

below is my `index.html` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>ngClassifieds</title>
  </head>
  <body ng-app = "ngClassifieds" ng-controller="classifiedsCtrl">

    <h1>{{name}}</h1>

    <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: you have not refered components/classifiedCtrl.js in the html

Answer (score 1):

You need to include your controller file below **app.js**

```
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/components/classifiedCtrl.js"></script>
```